# Aaggregate fact table sales based on a dim table column that are related through another dimension table in power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a situation, I want to get the reseller sales for "WASHINGTON REGION"; the database is "AdventureWorksDW2019" and I have the column relation as follows:

The geography details are populated in "DimGeography" table,

The reseller details are populated in "DimReseller" table, where each geography, say in my case, WASHINGTON could have more then reseller; hence, there is many-to-one relation between "DimReseller" and "DimGeography" and the column in relation is "GeographyKey"

The fact table "FactResellerSales" table is populated with reseller-sales; hence there is many-to-one relation between "FactResellerSales" and "DimReseller" tables; the column in relation is "ResellerKey"

```
--and the fact table has indirectly relation with "DimGeography" table
```

I am struggling generate a DAX query to get reseller-sales total belonging to "Washington"; could anyone help me understand to achieve this?

Thank you for giving your valuable time; pls find the screenshot of the schema diagram attached to this email.

[image]

Comment: it seems that both relations are active, so you just need to put the state from DimGeography and [SalesAmount] (aggregated as SUM) from FactResellerSales in the visual

Comment: Hello Stachu, I couldn't figure out further about how to build the DAX query /syntax? could you please help me on it... Thank you